# Getting leak of WKwebsiteDataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks, wkwebview

I am using wkwebview in a viewcontroller for loading html which is embbeded in uipageview controller . After swiping multi pageview , viewcontroller start lacking. So after using profile instrumnet i found that i am getting leak in wkwebsiteDatasource. I tried to clean cookies but issue still presist. In viewcontroller wkwebview deallocated properly as i checked in logs. Testing on iOS version 14.0.1 . I am attaching screenshot for more clear understanding.
[image]

Also attaching backtree image
[image]

Comment: May be you are adding `self` as `WKScriptMessageHandler`?

Comment: self.wkWebView.scrollView.bounces=false;
        self.wkWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
        self.wkWebView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true;
        self.wkWebView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = false;  
I am only using this setting for wkwebview @Cy-4AH